# tcltk add coulnm to tablelist as variable

Tags: tcl

```
tablelist::tablelist .t -columns { 0 "Name" 0 "Age" 0 "sex" 0 "ROLLNO" } -width 250 -height 15 -selectmode single
```

Now to add new column 'location' if I add as variable and pass to `insertcolumnlist` as below

```
set new_column "Location"
.t insertcolumnlist 4 {0 $new_column }
```

It gives below error

> can't read "new_column": no such variable

How to pass variable to `insertcolumnlist`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Braces prevent substitution in general. Using quotes instead or `[list]` (usually better than using quotes) will allow substitution:

```
.t insertcolumnlist 4 "0 $new_column"
```

or

```
.t insertcolumnlist 4 [list 0 $new_column]
```